# How to export Cypress env vars to pipeline

Tags: docker, dockerfile, environment-variables, cypress, codefresh

- I am writing an e2e automation with the following Structure

1. setup
2. tests
3. tearDown

- Each step runs in its docker container
  How do I export cypress env vars to codefresh pipeline which are created during setup and use them in the container running "tests" step

Comment: Are the variables only created during setup? And are they `Cypress.env()` variables or just general variables?

Comment: Yes, they are created during setup and they are part of cypress.env () in cypress.json. I can move them to .env by using dotenv package, but how can I export them to the pipeline and save them as a pipeline var.